# Displaying All Parent Pages as Featured Images

Tags: post-thumbnails

Here is a look at my current code to display all "children" pages of current post_parent (Also would be helpful to know how to display custom parent pages as well...)

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order'=>'ASC',
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if($my_query->have_posts()) :
    while($my_query->have_posts()) : 
        $my_query->the_post();
      // your stuff goes in this bit.
     if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : 
         $imgdata = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large' );
         $imgwidth = $imgdata[1]; // thumbnail's width
         $imgheight = $imgdata[2]; // thumbnail's height
  ?>
   <div class="child element isotope-item" style="width:<?php echo $imgwidth;?>;height:<?php echo $imgheight;?>;">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
      <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(large); ?>
      <span class="child_title"><?php echo the_title_attribute();?></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <?php
    endif;
    // end your stuff.
    endwhile;
else :
    // Do the no posts found message 
endif;
?>
</div>
```

Comment: What is a "custom parent page"? You already have the `$post` object for the parent or this code wouldn't work. Display that object the same way you displaying the children. Or, maybe "exactly what do you want to do with the parent?"

Comment: A custom parent page would be: I want "defined" parent pages to  be displayed as featured images on this page -- But back to my main issue -- how do I just display parent pages (as opposed to my code displaying children pages of post_parent) - I want all of the parent items (not just the one I'm currently on) - to display featured images on a page to create an image navigation structure.

Comment: When you say "all of the parent items", are you referring to all the posts returned by [`get_post_ancestors()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors), or all the "root" pages (ie, pages that have no ancestors)?

Comment: All of the "root" pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the "root" pages of a site:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'child_of' => 0,
);
$pages = get_pages( $args );
foreach( $pages as $page ) {
    if( has_post_thumbnail( $page->ID ) {
        $imgdata = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large' );
        $imgwidth = $imgdata[1]; // thumbnail's width
        $imgheight = $imgdata[2]; // thumbnail's height
    }
}
// handle the image as in your posted code
```

To get your custom post type, you should be able to replace `'post_type' => 'page'` with your CPT's name (eg, `'post_type' => 'my_post_type'`).

#### Reference

- [`get_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)